# Does Airflow cache global variable when rerun

Tags: python, airflow

I have a Airflow job like below:

```
import time

job_id = int(time.time())

airflow_job1 = PythonOperator(op_kwargs={"job_id" : job_id}, ...)
airflow_job2 = BashOperator(op_kwargs={"job_id" : job_id}, ...)

airflow_job1 >> airflow_job2
```

I know every time when script launched, I will have a new job_id, used in each airflow task. But I wonder what if I run the script from middle, like airflow_job1 failed, and I fix problem and rerun from airflow_job1 in UI,  is a new job_id generated in the rerun, or Airflow use the last job_id before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, after I check with a simple case:

```
# global parameter
job_id = int(time.time())


def airflow_job1(job_id, **context):
    print("in airflow_job1, current timestamp: %s" % job_id)

def airflow_job2(job_id, **context):
    print("in airflow_job2, current timestamp: %s" % job_id)

airflow_job1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='airflow_job1',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=airflow_job1,
    op_kwargs={'job_id': job_id},
    dag=globals()[dag_name]
)

airflow_job2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='airflow_job2',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=airflow_job2,
    op_kwargs={'job_id': job_id},
    dag=globals()[dag_name]
)

 airflow_job1 >> airflow_job2
```

I find job_id in airflow_job1 and airflow_job2 are different even if in the same run.

So the conclusion is that we shouldn't set global parameter in this way, maybe use xcom_pull / xcom_push to solve that